# Cannot get derived property from ZF2 Twitter user search

Tags: php, api, twitter, zend-framework2

I'm using ZF2 Twitter package to get user info by username and retrieve it's location, but the returned object doesn't give me the "derived" property, that should have the detailed data about location I want to use.

```
public function twitterAction()
{
    $config = array(
        'access_token' => array(
            'token' => 'MY TOKEN',
            'secret' => 'MY SECRET',
        ),
        'oauth_options' => array(
            'consumerKey' => 'MY CONSUMER KEY',
            'consumerSecret' => 'MY COMSUMER SECRET',
        ),
        'http_client_options' => array(
            'adapter' => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl',
            'curloptions' => array(
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            ),
        ),
    );
    $twitter = new Twitter($config);
    $response = $twitter->account->accountVerifyCredentials();
    if (!$response->isSuccess()) {
        die(var_dump($response->getErrors()));
    }
    $params = $this->params()->fromRoute();
    $profile = $params['profile'];
    $user = $twitter->users->show($profile);
    $coordinates = $user->derived->geo->coordinates;

    return new JsonModel(
     [
         'placeName' => $user->derived->locality . ' - ' $user->derived->region,
         'link' => 'http://www.google.com/maps/place/'.$coordinates[0].','.$coordinates[1]
     ]
 );
}
```

I'm using [the twitter api page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/enrichments/overview/profile-geo) as reference

this is the response I get if I return the user

```
{
    'placename: ': '-',
    'link: ': 'http://www.google.com/maps/place/,',
}
```

How can I retrieve this data?

Comment: Hi there. Do you have any code to share? What did you try? What was in the data that you *did* get returned? Was the property there but was it empty? We're going to need a lot more data before we can help you out.

Comment: I'll add information to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From that page:

> Profile Geo data will be included in Twitter's PowerTrack, Replay, Volume Stream, Search, and Historical PowerTrack APIs.

I *think* that means the geo data is only available for [paying customers of PowerTrack](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/overview/powertrack-api.html).  If you're just a regular developer, you can't get it.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll have to find another way to do it

Thanks